# Unable to train model in Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, naivebayes

I am trying to classify email as spam/ham using NLTK

Below are the steps followed :

1. Trying to extract all the tokens
2. Fetching all the features
3. Extracting features from the corpus of all unique words and mapping
   True/false
4. Training the data in Naive Bayes classifier

---

```
from nltk.classify.util import apply_features
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
import pandas as pd
import collections
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from collections import Counter
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/venkat1017/Data/master/emails.csv')

"""fetch array of tuples where each tuple is defined by (tokenized_text, label)
"""

processed_tokens=data['text'].apply(lambda x:([x for x in x.split() if x.isalpha()]))
processed_tokens=processed_tokens.apply(lambda x:([x for x in x if len(x)>3]))

processed_tokens = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(processed_tokens,data['spam'])]



"""
 dictword return a Set of unique words in complete corpus.
"""

list = zip(*processed_tokens)

dictionary = Counter(word for i, j in processed_tokens for word in i)

dictword = [word for word, count in dictionary.items() if count == 1]


"""maps each input text into feature vector"""

y_dict = ( [ (word, True) for word in dictword] )
feature_vec=dict(y_dict)

"""Training"""

training_set, testing_set = train_test_split(y_dict, train_size=0.7)

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

---

```
    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py in train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator)
    197         for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
    198             label_freqdist[label] += 1
--> 199             for fname, fval in featureset.items():
    200                 # Increment freq(fval|label, fname)
    201                 feature_freqdist[label, fname][fval] += 1

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I am facing with the following error when trying to train the corpus of unique words

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I hope you're aware that `y_dict` is just a dictionary which maps words (strings) which have occurred only once in the corpus as keys to the value `True`. You're passing it as a training set to the classifier, whereas you ought be a passing a `tuple` of (feature dict of each text row), and (the corresponding label). While your classifier should be receiving `[({'feat1': 'value1', ... }, label_value), ...]` as input, you're passing `[ ('word1', True), ... ]`. The `string` type has no `items` attribute, only `dict` does. Hence the error.

Secondly, your data modelling is wrong. Your training set should consist of a feature dict derived from `data['text']` mapped to the `data['spam']` value (since that is your label). Please look at how to perform document classification with nltk's classsifiers in section 1.3 [here](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).